# Deserialize javascript array on c#

Tags: javascript, c#, json

I'm trying to send JSON array from javascript to c# but I always get errors on deserializing.
First I tried to serialize the normal js array `JSON.stringify(order)` but on c# I get

Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'Order[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.

```
Order[] order = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order[]>(json); //this is line with error
```

After that I tried to convert js array to object and after that serialize to json

```
function toObject(arr) {
var rv = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i)
    rv[i] = arr[i];
return rv;
}

{"0":["Item1","2"],"1":["Item2","1"]} //JSON
```

That is how JSON looks like now, but again same error.

Comment: It looks like you're trying to deserialize object instead of an array. Can you show how json looked like before you've made it converted with the toObject function?

Comment: Looks like this: [["Item1","2"],["Item2","1"]]

Comment: So you are sending from javascript array of arrays. If you want JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Order[]>(json) to deserialize it to Order[], you need to make sure, that you are sending array of objects e.g. [{"Name":"Item1", "Id": 1},{"Name":"Item2","Id": 2}]

Comment: Yes but my dynamic array don't have arguments (names)

Comment: Im just creating array like this                                                                                   
    `let array = new Array();
    array[0] = iname;
    array[1] = amount;
    order.push(array);`

Comment: You need to do something similar to this 
`let ob = {};
ob['Name'] = "Item1";
ob['Amount'] = 1;
order.push(ob)`.
You need to remember, data structures you want to serialize/deserialize must have same fields in c# and javascript (I'm guessing that Order type in c# has fields 'Name' and 'Amount', you need to adjust this to what you really have)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227810/discussion-between-tenso-and-nina).

Answer (score -1):

Look at JsonConvert.DeserializeObject it is a Newtonsoft library.